# App isn't compatible with my device why?

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

I put new app in Google Play developer Console yesterday, 
today I was try download app from this link

[My app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz)

but i can't because, my app isn't compatible with my device (why?)
its't the same app like app which I have in developer console for some months and everythinf okay. 
difference between this app and app which public for months..
language,
in developer console in folder distribution have Czech rapublic like in older app Slovakia.

and other key (.jks) (.json--- download from goole site [with my app id])

[older app slovakia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.tipos.paradox02.citaj)

I don't know how need write here, if you need mor info please write I put...

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {

        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz'
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '2'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
}
```

this is manifest (generated)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest android:versionName="2" android:versionCode="1" package="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="11"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<!-- Optional permission for App measurement to run. -->


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<permission android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>


-<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:supportsRtl="true" android:largeHeap="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true">

<!-- > ↓ sledovanie <! -->


<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


+<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver" android:enabled="true">







<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>


-<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFFERRER"/>

</intent-filter>

</receiver>

<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"/>

<!-- > ↑ sledovanie <! -->



-<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Citaj" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>


-<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Loto535" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:label="@string/title_activity_loto535">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>


-<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.EuroMil" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:label="@string/title_activity_euro_mil">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>


-<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Index" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:label="@string/title_activity_index">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>


-<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.INfo" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" android:label="Tip">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>


-<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Bonus" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>


-<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.INfo2">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Tahak"/>

<activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Loto_plus"/>


-<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" android:enabled="true">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD"/>

</intent-filter>

</receiver>

<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>


-<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>

<category android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz"/>

</intent-filter>

</receiver>

<!-- Internal (not exported) receiver used by the app to start its own exported services without risk of being spoofed. -->


<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false"/>

<!-- FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime, no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true" -->



-<service android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">


-<intent-filter android:priority="-500">

<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>

</intent-filter>

</service>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false"/>

<provider android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" android:authorities="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.firebaseinitprovider"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

manifest which i can edit in androidstudio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <!-- > ↓ sledovanie                                                                          <! -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

    <!-- > ↑ sledovanie                                                                                  <! -->

    <activity
        android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Citaj"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Loto535"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_loto535"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.EuroMil"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_euro_mil"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Index"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_index"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.INfo"
        android:label="Tip"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Bonus"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.INfo2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Tahak"></activity>
    <activity android:name="sk.sazka.paradox02.BiliUz.Loto_plus"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: check if there are any differences in generated manifests:

`app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I put up generated and original, it's similar, but in generated it's more info. it's good?

Comment: It is normal , libraries add some permissions to manifest. I’ve been meaning that you check the generated manifest of both apps. You can also check if both apps require the same funcionalities / features in google developer console (in details of recently uploaded apk file)

Comment: post your device configuration

Comment: where i find device configuration

Comment: it's  the same manifest between this two app. I thing so I somewhere unblock permisson downdload only for czech/slovak republic and If in new app unbloack permission in czech republic and now I'am in slovak and have Slovak SIM card then i can't download now it.

Answer (score 0):

I rebiuld project and put new apk.

and I put two destinations slovak & czech and ewerything be okay.

Thanks for HELP